# EJB 2.1: Prevent Bean passivation immediately after it is activated

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-2.x

Running a ejb 2.1 entity bean on jboss 6.3. This bean is being passivated immediately after its activated. any idea why this happens, and is it possible to stop it from happening for at least a few seconds.

This happens between method calls.

I can't post any src as i would get fired!

This is a continuation of this question.
[EJB 2.1 doesn't preserve state across method calls in jboss 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785359/ejb-2-1-doesnt-preserve-state-across-method-calls-in-jboss-6-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jboss 6.3 only has transaction commit-option 3 support (something similar to it at least)

What is a commit-option? It is the control we have on the entity beans state at transaction commit time.

what is commit-option 3? "Pooled bean: At the end of the transaction, neither the instance nor its state is valid (instance will be passivated and returned to the pool). Every client call causes an ejbActivate, ejbLoad, then the business method, then ejbStore, and ejbPassivate"

based on the migration guide for 6.3

"In JBoss EAP 5.x, it was also possible to customize caching, pooling, commit-options, and the interceptor stack. In JBoss EAP 6, this is no longer possible. There is only one implementation, which is similar to the Instance Per Transaction policy with commit-option C"